# Is there a way to render files from a MySQL database into a website?

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

I'm tasked to build a web document management system where files (PDFs, and perhaps images) will be uploaded and viewed later in the website. Currently what I have is the upload goes into MySQl workbench, in a longblob data type field.

I want to render the files on the webpage somewhat like research journal websites that have a PDF viewer of some sort in their pages.

I tried selecting the File value off the database table, and placing it in iframe's src attribute but it does not do anything. Though iframe does render the file if given a file address on my computer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should not save file in mysql!
Its better to save the file somewhere on your host then give the files links to the mysql and for rendering it you should load files from their links.
Or You can use other tricks ...
I personally use this trick !

Comment: MySQL has [`BLOB` column type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html) ("binary large object that can hold a variable amount of data"), which the OP is already using. What's your rationale to say it cannot be done?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I know, I said its better to save it like file and put its link in msql !

Comment: You edited your answer 7 minutes ago to say that (which is fine). My comment was about the original wording.

Answer (score 1):

The src attribute contains an URL, not file content. You should make the src attribute name an URL that calls a code handler. Then develop the code for that handler, which loads the content from the database and returns it as the response, after setting the response header for "Content-Type: application/pdf".